# Is there a way to identify which perl specific options are passed to a script?

Tags: perl

I'm aware a script can retrieve all the command line arguments passed to it through ARGV, i.e.:

```
# test.pl

print "$ARGV[0]\n";
print "$ARGV[1]\n";
print "$ARGV[2]\n";

## perl ./test.pl one two three
one
two
three
```

In the above example, the command line arguments passed to the `test.pl` script are "one", "two" and "three".

Now, suppose I run the following command:

```
## perl -d:DumpTrace test.pl one two three

or

## perl -c test.pl one two three
```

How can I tell from within the operations of the `test.pl` script that the options `-c` or `-d:DumpTrace` were passed to the perl interpreter?

I'm looking for a method that will identify when options are passed to the perl interpreter during the execution of a script:

```
if "-c" was used in the execution of `test.pl` script {
    print "perl -c option was used in the execution of this script";
}
```

Comment: Even if you could do it, the `print` would not produce anything, as `-c` doesn't run the script (unless you put the whole if into a BEGIN block).

Comment: See also [Devel::PL_origargv](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/TOBYINK/Devel-PL_origargv-0.004/lib/Devel/PL_origargv.pm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Devel::PL_origargv](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/TOBYINK/Devel-PL_origargv-0.004/lib/Devel/PL_origargv.pm) to get access to to command line parameters that was passed to the `perl` interpreter. Example script `p.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::PL_origargv;
my @PL_origargv = Devel::PL_origargv->get;
print Dumper({args => \@PL_origargv});
```

Then running the script like this for example:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -I. p.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'args' => [
                      'perl',
                      '-MData::Dumper',
                      '-I.',
                      'p.pl'
                    ]
        };
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need. Only problem is that the module `Devel::PL_origargv` is not built into perl. It's an extra module I have to get.  Is there a way to get around this?  I dont want to require users to have to worry about getting this package.  Is there an efficient way to include the content of the module in the `p.pl` script itself?

Comment: @KLZY As mentioned by toolic, it is an XS module so the users need to compile it on their machine before they can use it. However, you can try compile the module into an executable using e.g. [PAR::Packer::pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) and then distribute that executable to your users. Though, I believe this requires that the users use the same architecture and perl version as you.

Comment: @KLZY Despite its name, this may not get you the "original" command line, see e.g. `perl -MDevel::PL_origargv -le '$0="lol -cat"; print Devel::PL_origargv->get'`. And frankly, I don't see the purpose of it: why can't you just write a wrapper?